# MenuItem on Navigation Drawer does not respond

Tags: java, android

i am new to java programming, now i am working on a simple app that has an webview integrated that open a particular website.
My style is navigation drawer for the app. When i press an item from the drawer menu it doesn't work at all. I am trying to open a URL using the webview but nothing happens.
I have tried many things i found on here but i cant get any results

```
package com.virsoft.alfagreece;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.virsoft.alfagreece.ui.home.HomeFragment;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    private WebView myWebView;



    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    @Override        
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent Email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                Email.setType("text/email");
                Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                        new String[]{"sales@test.com"});
                Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                        "testApp"); // Email 's Subject
                Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi test," + "");  //Email 's Greeting text
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(Email, "Send message"));
            }
        });


        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        myWebView =(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings=myWebView.getSettings();
        myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(webSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.test.com");
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            myWebView.loadUrl("https://youtube.com");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return true;
        }

        else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

            myWebView.loadUrl("https://yahoo.com");

            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting up a small sample and doing some debugging, it seems to me that a `NavigationView` can be controlled either by setting up navigation with `NavController` or by setting a `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`. You can't have both of them.

So if you want to keep on using Navigation components (which should by all means be possible), the question is how to get notified of clicks on `NavigationView` items?

`NavController` will navigate to some destination, nothing more. But using the [safeargs plugin](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data), one can pass along argument values to the destination `Fragment`.

If you use always the same destination (`Fragment`) but with different URLs, you could associate each `NavigationView` item with a specific `action` in the navigation graph which in turn belongs to one specific URL.

In my sample app, `NavController` replaced an already visible `HomeFragment` with a new instance of `HomeFragment` and the new URL was passed in correctly.

`MainActivity` `onCreate()` (note that you can remove everything related to `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` from `MainActivity`):

```
private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.nav_home)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}
```

Basic declaration of arguments in navigation graph:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    android:name="com.example.navdrawerissue.HomeFragment"
    android:label="fragment_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
    <argument
        android:name="webUrl"
        app:argType="string"
        android:defaultValue="https://developer.android.com"/>
</fragment>
```

Declaration of global `action` in navigation graph (below `fragment`, not nested!)

```
<action android:id="@+id/nav_other" app:destination="@+id/nav_home">
    <argument
        android:name="webUrl"
        app:argType="string"
        android:defaultValue="https://youtube.com" />
</action>
```

`NavigationView` menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:title="nav_home"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_plusone"

        android:title="plus one"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_other"

        android:title="other"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Yes you are right i tried your way and it showed everything normally and it worked finally!!! Thank you for your time & support! It work also if i put everything from main_activity.java realting to webview after onCreate inside Fragment1.java

Comment: @RuslanYefimets - thanks for letting me know, and good luck with your project :)